# Responsive Html Template

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email

hello i have to code responsive html email template what i want  you to clear  me will my template be responsive if i add media queires for  different resolutions   for example sometging like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
table[class=wrapper]
{
    width:100% !important;
}
table[class=main_table]
{
    width:320px !important;
    width:100% !important;
}
```

(this is just piece of cod to clear my point ofcourse i have to add this for whole template  )

so will template be responsive  if i add these queries  ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using `table[class=wrapper]` instead of `table.wrapper`? Also, you don't want these `!important` marks there.

Comment: Judging on the nature of your question, I'd check here first. http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps You can get the gist of it within a few minutes really.

Comment: One more thing, if you're planning on manually re-adjusting your layout to fit every resolution - don't. Get familiar with with Twitter Bootstrap. It will make your life and workflow much more efficient.

Comment: good suggestions  ,it maybe a stupid question but really helpful for m e.and i m sure will help many  mor

Comment: The [class method](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3457/media-query-issues-in-yahoo-mail-mobile-email/) is a technique used by email designers to prevent Yahoo from displaying media queries by default. I believe the bug has been resolved by Yahoo recently.

Comment: @DiH Bootstrap is not appropriate for email design.

Comment: I somehow didn't notice that 'email' in the question. I would disagree with you to some extent though. Even though compressed bootstrap styles are quite an overkill for an e-mail, I can't find a reason why it would not be appropriate for email design. It comes with a lot of handy styling that you can use. That concerns styles of course. I would strongly advise not to try to glue Bootstrap JS into the email

Answer (score 0):

Adding media queries will make your email 'responsive', providing it is set up correctly and functional of course. In your example you'd need to add those classes to the appropriate tables for them to take effect. So as a general rule, using media queries = responsive.

An excellent responsive template to start with is [this one](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_a_free_responsive_email_template_using_media_queries_-_part_i) by Email on Adid.